# Spring-Boot_1.4.2 -embeeded tomcat startup issue

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8

I migrated my project to spring-boot_1.4.2. It comes in-built with tomcat_8.5.6 version. While starting the application from command line I am getting jaxb-api dependency error.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\sswain\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-xjc\2.2.4-1\jaxb-api.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:60) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:48) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:338) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:288) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262) [tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104) [tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:101) [tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

Comment: Your maven cache is corrupted. Delete that jar and try to download it again.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted the apache-cxf dependency from the maven and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

That exception usually means that a file downloaded from a Maven repository got corrupted. The easiest is to remove the file from your local repository since it will be downloaded again the next time you build the project.